# PHP PDO why select only first row in Database table?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am PDO newbie, and i can't figure why i can select only first row in Table on database.

This is my DataBase TABLE :

```
    Column  Type    Null    Default     Comments
    id  int(11) No       
    cred    varchar(20) No       
    tok     char(40)    No       
    ptok    char(40)    No       
    t   char(128)   No       
    expires     varchar(26) No       
    Indexes
    Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
    PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  id  1   A   No  
    ptok    BTREE   Yes No  ptok    1   A   No
```

And this is my SELECT (find) function :

```
 public function findTriplet($credential,$token, $persistentToken) {

    $sql = "SELECT IF(SHA1(?) = {$this->tokenColumn}, 1, -1) AS token_match " .
           "FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE {$this->credentialColumn} = ? " .
           "AND {$this->persistentTokenColumn} = SHA1(?) LIMIT 1 ";

    $query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

    $query->execute(array($token, $credential, $persistentToken));

    $result = $query->fetchColumn();

    if(!$result) {
      return self::TRIPLET_NOT_FOUND;
    }
    elseif ($result == 1) {
      return self::TRIPLET_FOUND;
    }
    else {
      return self::TRIPLET_INVALID;
    }
  }
```

Anyway i tryed to search for answer , but i dont know PDO so good so its not matter..

I tryed play with that , no succses..
Anyone know what is my problem in the findTriplet function and what i am doing wrong ?
It will only select first database row so if i have more then 1 row's it will return false.

Thanks allot.

Comment: Try reading the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php): _Returns a single column from the next row of a result set or FALSE if there are no more rows._ If you want to get multiple rows, you have to call it multiple times.

Comment: @Your Common Sense, Yea afcours , please dont comment if you dont like ,i make tests , and the problem is came from PDO / SQL query i am not sure which one, and it's will select only from first row.

Comment: @Barmar , thanks i will read and will try.

Comment: @Barmar , my code using the same proper way like in PHP doc's . its still select only first row from Database Table. Maybe it's database table wrong properties?

Comment: It's not clear how your function should work with multiple rows. What if one of them contains 1 and another contains -1, should the function return `TRIPLET_FOUND` or `TRIPLET_INVALID`?

Comment: it's will return in each case diffrent , if the token found it will return FOUND else will return INVALID .. its not the problem , again the problem is "Why it select only from first row even if i have 10 row's " ? and Quotes from PHP doc's : "fetchColumn return boolean false when a row not is found or don't had more rows." so i dont know why it's not working..

Comment: BTW , i using   const TRIPLET_FOUND     =  1,
        TRIPLET_NOT_FOUND =  0,
        TRIPLET_INVALID   = -1;

Answer (score -1):

Remove "LIMIT 1" from your variable and see if results change:

```
$sql = "SELECT IF(SHA1(?) = {$this->tokenColumn}, 1, -1) AS token_match " .
       "FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE {$this->credentialColumn} = ? " .
       "AND {$this->persistentTokenColumn} = SHA1(?) LIMIT 1 ";
```

Becomes:

```
$sql = "SELECT IF(SHA1(?) = {$this->tokenColumn}, 1, -1) AS token_match " .
           "FROM {$this->tableName} WHERE {$this->credentialColumn} = ? " .
           "AND {$this->persistentTokenColumn} = SHA1(?)";
```

It appears you are retrieving a match, so you are seeing a SINGLE result. I'm not sure of the application, but you might want to keep a Limit in the SQL statement. Removing the LIMIT will at least be a good testing point.

Comment: Thanks , but the first thing i'v tryed it's was this : remove the LIMIT 1 , it's not working.

Comment: Barmar is correct above when he mentions the fetchcolumn issue you are facing. You need to use an alternative $query->fetch command (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) or specify a column count for fetchColumn to return against.